# Can I still use global $var inside a function in a laravel view?

Tags: php, laravel

I am a beginner in Laravel and I am trying to move an existing Project (in native php) to the laravel framework.

Everything so far is working great, except the part where I am trying to execute static functions from my helper classes.

I got a view called old.php, which looks like this:

```
$my_global_var = 'Hello';

class TestClass {
    public static function foo(){
        global $my_global_var;
        return $my_global_var;
    }
}

dd(TestClass::foo());
```

And instead of returning "Hello" like it used to, the function returns `null` instead.

I know I could just pass `$my_global_var` as a parameter instead, but as I mentioned before, I am trying to move an existing project to laravel. And that project is full of helper classes like TestClass, that are included at the beginning (or autoloaded) and then used throughout the entire programm.

My Question is: Do I have to rewrite all of my helper classes, or is there a way for me to keep the `global $my_global_var;` line?

Comment: The difference is not *can I* - but *should I*.

Comment: can you add a little more context? what is this global variable about? its much better to provide a better approach on your case instead of using a band aid solution

Comment: @NigelRen  If i _could_ I wouldn't. But I am limited by the technology of my time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```php
global $my_global_var; // Here is your answer
$my_global_var = 'Hello';

class TestClass {
    public static function foo(){
        global $my_global_var;
        return $my_global_var;
    }
}

dd(TestClass::foo());
```

Answer (score 0):

In you example, you can access the `$my_global_var` in your function using [$GLOBALS[]](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php). More info [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).

Example:

```
$my_global_var = 'Hello';

class TestClass {
    public static function foo(){
        return $GLOBALS['my_global_var'];
    }
}

dd(TestClass::foo());
```